# change loop output to per line instead of a group

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto

I am trying to get a desired output for rest of my script to work...currently when i assign a varaible called "st", i get the below output...but note that one of the lines i get a cidr block of "[2.2.2.2/32, 12.12.12.12/32, 13.13.13.13/32, 14.14.14.14/32, 15.15.15.15/32]"....how can i break this down so i get a desired output(look at very end for this)....

i want the final output to be something like below...note how the big CIDR block is broken down so now it is on 5 lines instead of 1 line

```
......
......
......
(SecurityGroup:Full blown SG test, u'sg-3ff65858', 'inbound:', IPPermissions:tcp(389-389), ' source:', [10.10.10.10/32])
(SecurityGroup:Full blown SG test, u'sg-3ff65858', 'inbound:', IPPermissions:-1(None-None), ' source:', [2.2.2.2/32])
(SecurityGroup:Full blown SG test, u'sg-3ff65858', 'inbound:', IPPermissions:-1(None-None), ' source:', [12.12.12.12/32])
(SecurityGroup:Full blown SG test, u'sg-3ff65858', 'inbound:', IPPermissions:-1(None-None), ' source:', [13.13.13.13/32])
(SecurityGroup:Full blown SG test, u'sg-3ff65858', 'inbound:', IPPermissions:-1(None-None), ' source:', [14.14.14.14/32])
(SecurityGroup:Full blown SG test, u'sg-3ff65858', 'inbound:', IPPermissions:-1(None-None), ' source:', [15.15.15.15/32])
(SecurityGroup:Full blown SG test, u'sg-3ff65858', 'inbound:', IPPermissions:udp(53-53), ' source:', [7.7.7.7/32])
......
......
......
```

So i thought maybe i can use the length function on rules.grants and if its is greater than 1 then build a diff "st" variable.

```
(SecurityGroup:Full blown SG test, u'sg-3ff65858', 'inbound:', IPPermissions:-1(None-None), ' source:', [sg-c65a20a3-995635159130])
(SecurityGroup:Full blown SG test, u'sg-3ff65858', 'inbound:', IPPermissions:-1(None-None), ' source:', [sg-99c4befc-995635159130])
(SecurityGroup:Full blown SG test, u'sg-3ff65858', 'inbound:', IPPermissions:tcp(110-110), ' source:', [9.9.9.9/32])
(SecurityGroup:Full blown SG test, u'sg-3ff65858', 'inbound:', IPPermissions:tcp(0-443), ' source:', [4.4.4.4/32])
(SecurityGroup:Full blown SG test, u'sg-3ff65858', 'inbound:', IPPermissions:tcp(443-443), ' source:', [0.0.0.0/0])
(SecurityGroup:Full blown SG test, u'sg-3ff65858', 'inbound:', IPPermissions:icmp(-1--1), ' source:', [3.3.3.3/32])
(SecurityGroup:Full blown SG test, u'sg-3ff65858', 'inbound:', IPPermissions:tcp(3306-3306), ' source:', [5.5.5.5/32])
(SecurityGroup:Full blown SG test, u'sg-3ff65858', 'inbound:', IPPermissions:-1(None-None), ' source:', [sg-35568d51-995635159130])
(SecurityGroup:Full blown SG test, u'sg-3ff65858', 'inbound:', IPPermissions:tcp(0-65535), ' source:', [1.1.1.1/32])
(SecurityGroup:Full blown SG test, u'sg-3ff65858', 'inbound:', IPPermissions:tcp(389-389), ' source:', [10.10.10.10/32])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#206>", line 4, in <module>
    st = sg, sg.id, "inbound:", rule, " source:", rule.grants[sg]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not SecurityGroup
>>>
```

Any thought on how i can achive this ?

I tried what @helloV had asked and that seemed to did the trick...but note how that cidr block for the lines(additional lines) now dont have a list bracket.....for lines that have 2.2.2.2/32, 12.12.12.12/32, 13.13.13.13/32, 14.14.14.14/32

```
(SecurityGroup:Full blown SG test, u'sg-3ff65858', 'inbound:', IPPermissions:-1(None-None), ' source:', [sg-c65a20a3-995635159130])
(SecurityGroup:Full blown SG test, u'sg-3ff65858', 'inbound:', IPPermissions:-1(None-None), ' source:', [sg-99c4befc-995635159130])
(SecurityGroup:Full blown SG test, u'sg-3ff65858', 'inbound:', IPPermissions:tcp(110-110), ' source:', [9.9.9.9/32])
(SecurityGroup:Full blown SG test, u'sg-3ff65858', 'inbound:', IPPermissions:tcp(0-443), ' source:', [4.4.4.4/32])
(SecurityGroup:Full blown SG test, u'sg-3ff65858', 'inbound:', IPPermissions:tcp(443-443), ' source:', [0.0.0.0/0])
(SecurityGroup:Full blown SG test, u'sg-3ff65858', 'inbound:', IPPermissions:icmp(-1--1), ' source:', [3.3.3.3/32])
(SecurityGroup:Full blown SG test, u'sg-3ff65858', 'inbound:', IPPermissions:tcp(3306-3306), ' source:', [5.5.5.5/32])
(SecurityGroup:Full blown SG test, u'sg-3ff65858', 'inbound:', IPPermissions:-1(None-None), ' source:', [sg-35568d51-995635159130])
(SecurityGroup:Full blown SG test, u'sg-3ff65858', 'inbound:', IPPermissions:tcp(0-65535), ' source:', [1.1.1.1/32])
(SecurityGroup:Full blown SG test, u'sg-3ff65858', 'inbound:', IPPermissions:tcp(389-389), ' source:', [10.10.10.10/32])
(SecurityGroup:Full blown SG test, u'sg-3ff65858', 'inbound:', IPPermissions:-1(None-None), ' source:', 2.2.2.2/32)
(SecurityGroup:Full blown SG test, u'sg-3ff65858', 'inbound:', IPPermissions:-1(None-None), ' source:', 12.12.12.12/32)
(SecurityGroup:Full blown SG test, u'sg-3ff65858', 'inbound:', IPPermissions:-1(None-None), ' source:', 13.13.13.13/32)
(SecurityGroup:Full blown SG test, u'sg-3ff65858', 'inbound:', IPPermissions:-1(None-None), ' source:', 14.14.14.14/32)
(SecurityGroup:Full blown SG test, u'sg-3ff65858', 'inbound:', IPPermissions:-1(None-None), ' source:', 15.15.15.15/32)
(SecurityGroup:Full blown SG test, u'sg-3ff65858', 'inbound:', IPPermissions:udp(53-53), ' source:', [7.7.7.7/32])
(SecurityGroup:Full blown SG test, u'sg-3ff65858', 'inbound:', IPPermissions:tcp(25-25), ' source:', [11.11.11.11/32])
(SecurityGroup:Full blown SG test, u'sg-3ff65858', 'inbound:', IPPermissions:tcp(53-53), ' source:', [8.8.8.8/32])
(SecurityGroup:Full blown SG test, u'sg-3ff65858', 'inbound:', IPPermissions:tcp(5439-5439), ' source:', [6.6.6.6/32])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop through the rule.grants

```
for rule in sg.rules:
  if len(rule.grants) > 1:
    for grant in rule.grants:
      st = sg, sg.id, "inbound:", rule, " source:", [grant]
      print st
  else:
      st = sg, sg.id, "inbound:", rule, " source:", rule.grants
      print st
```

Comment: looks like that work but it does not populate it as a list...any idea how to fix that ?

Comment: Thank you that actually fixed all my code.  I guess i really had a long day missing such silly things...